# Cannot refund order from third-party payment gateway

Tags: shopify, shopify-app

We're building a third-party Shopify payment app and we're encountering issues with refunds.

Our test orders do not contain a Refund button, but a Restock button instead, and when you click that, it shows "This is a free order."

We cannot test refunds at all as doing Restock or Cancel does not trigger refund or void session.

Anyone knows how to resolve this issue?

Answer (score -1):

Would you not provide an Admin link targeted at the order details screen? That would contain a refund link, sending the order ID to your App for processing, at which point you'd provide the merchant with an easy way to perform refunds?

I think that is the easiest way, otherwise you have to rely on Shopify interfacing to your App and payment gateway, which is probably not something you've negotiated or performed.

Comment: The order details page (in the shopify admin dashboard) does not contain a refund button when it is paid via our payment app, only restock, and it's showing a free order.
However, when we use a different payment method, it's showing a refund button.

Comment: You did not read my comment! You need to handle refunds yourself. Place a link in the order more actions button. When other payment methods offer a refund button it is because they are integrated tighter with Shopify.

Comment: It does not say it like that in the docs though: https://shopify.dev/apps/payments/processing-a-refund

Comment: I see. From that then, maybe you never setup your payment App for refunds in the first place. If Shopify cannot see your refund end point, then that might explain why you see no refund button.

Comment: I set it up. It's just adding a refund session url.

Comment: This is what it looks like on the order page in admin dashboard: [order page](https://i.ibb.co/ngnrZ1s/A2-B2-AEEB-C034-4-A8-F-883-E-617-BFADE1963-4-5005-c.jpg). Also, I noticed in the history, the gateway is undefined: [order history](https://i.ibb.co/vv6Hd18/CBDED78-C-20-DC-41-AA-9-F74-EAFA7-AC7-EBB3.jpg).

Comment: Clearly, it helps to read the docs and set up all the endpoints!

Comment: I think you misunderstood my comment. The refund session URL is set since the beginning, but it still does not work. No refund button is shown. Doing restock/cancel does not call refund endpoint.

Comment: Talk to Shopify. No one on SO can help you.